# less than 90 day internship in Germany for Non-EU citizen with a residence permit in EU country

Tags: visa, internship

I have a Hungarian residence permit (study purpose) but South Korean passport. I am aware that South Korea can enter Germany without a visa and entitled to stay up to 90days. Also on the embassy website, it said non-EU citizen with EU country residence permit can enter without a visa.

The internship is for 2 months and non-paid.

I am confused whether I need to apply for German residence permit once I arrive for this internship since it is less than 90 days and non-paid. Will I be exempt from applying for residence permit for internship purpose?

I really would appreciate your help, because I've seen questions regarding internship visa but not about residence permit after the arrival.